# How can I run hunspell on a list of files with xargs?

Tags: xargs, spellcheck

When I run

```
find . -name "*.html" | xargs hunspell
```

hunspell displays the first file with an spelling error, but won't accept input.  I have to ctrl-c to kill it.  What causes this?

Is there a way to run hunspell across a list of files in a directory tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`find . -name "*.html" -exec hunspell '{}' \;`